# What's the default `Router.navigate()` behavior about query params?

Tags: angular, angular-router

The `navigate()` method from `Router` takes a `queryParamsHandling` option that, if set, can either be `merge` or `preserve`.

What's the default behavior of the `Router` when it comes to query params?

Answer (score 0):

Even though the options are:

- `merge` will join the existing query params with the ones you pass to the `navigate()` method under the `queryParams` property. If any are repeated, the new one it's used.
- `preserve` will use the ones already there. Used when you don't need any additional query params.

The funny thing is that none of these options it's the default. By default, `Router.navigate()` will drop the existing params or replace them with the ones you provide.